# Redux data is not updating in the UI after fetching data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am now making a react native app.

In my app I got my profile screen
and in the `profile screen` I got an `edit button` which will lead to the edit screen

Inside my profile screen I am using `useDispatch` to request to an api.`fetchAuthMember`is requesting user data

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      await dispatch(fetchAuthMember(token.access_token));
      await dispatch(fetchCountryList());
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

and I am rendering like this in the profile component

```
const renderItem = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.profileTitle}>
          <Icon2 name="user-o" size={30} color="black" />
          <Text style={styles.titleFont}> My Profile</Text>
           <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
             <Text style={styles.firstName}>{userInfo.FirstName}</Text>
             <Text style={styles.lastName}>{userInfo.LastName}</Text>
           </View>
        </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonHalfWidth}
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate('EditProfile', {
              screen: 'EditProfile',
              params: {
                firstName: userInfo.FirstName,
                lastName: userInfo.LastName,
              },
            })
          }>
          <Icon2 name="edit" size={30} color="#0382C4" />
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Edit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

So when I press the edit button. It will navigate to the `edit screen`.
In the edit screen

I am updating data like this when user press the button

```
        let dataToSend = {
            FirstName: FirstName,
            LastName: LastName,
        };
        console.log(dataToSend)

        await dispatch(updateMemberInfo(token.access_token, dataToSend));
        await dispatch(fetchAuthMember(token.access_token));
        navigation.navigate('MyProfile');
```

As you can see I am using `async and await`, and I am also reusing the `fetchAuthMember` here.
Which will fetch the user another time. After that navigate to `profile` page. The thing is

The first name and last name on my `profile page` is not being updated. But If I try to call it in post man. I can see the data updated. Is there anything I am missing?

**actions**

```
 export const fetchAuthMember = (token) => (dispatch) => {
        alert('fetching member')
      axios
        .get(`${baseUri}/api/members`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          dispatch({
            type: FETCH_USERINFO,
            payload: res.data,
          });
        });
    };

export const updateMemberInfo = (token, data) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .put(`${baseUri}/api/members/edit`, data, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_USERINFO,
                payload: res.data,
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
};
```

reducer

```
export const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGGED_IN:
      return {...state, token: action.payload, loggedIn: true};
    case LOGGED_OUT:
      return {...state, token: '', loggedIn: false};
    case FETCH_USERINFO:
      return {...state, userInfo: action.payload};
    case UPDATE_USERINFO:
      return {...state};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: `dispatch` isn't `async` so it's unclear why you wait for them. What do these asynchronous actions do, how do they update state in your reducer(s), and how does your UI subscribe to your redux store for changes?

Comment: @DrewReese You can await dispatching a thunk action with `await dispatch(thunkAction(arg))` or `await thunkAction(arg)(dispatch)` I prefer the second one when possible (given the thunkAction doesn't need getState) so you can see your're waiting for a thunk action. For this to work the thunkAction has to return a promise though.

Comment: Your actions seem to be missing from your question. If they're thunk actions then make sure you **return** a promise from them:  `const thunkAction = arg => dispatch => { return asyncStuff.then((result)=>dispatch(something(result)))}`

Comment: @HMR You are correct ***if*** the dispatched *action* returns a Promise, but OP seems to be handling all the asynchronous calls in an effect hook and not in a thunk though. It's not clear what these actions are doing, thus the request for more context.

Comment: Okay I will also include the action calls

Comment: `UPDATE_USERINFO` action doesn't do anything but return a shallow copy of state, it doesn't consume the action payload. Can you also include how your profile component is pulling your redux state?

Comment: @DrewReese The `UPDATE_USERINFO` doesn't have any payload. The api only return that status is 200. and the operation is successful. It doesn't contain the updated First name and last name

Comment: Ah, you dispatch that action with a payload of `res.data`, so if it's empty or you don't use it you might want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In your actions do the following: `return axios...`, at the moment your actions are not returning a promise (as commented twice).

Comment: Hi
I try to implement what you said, But I am getting promise rejection error.

I think I am doing it wrongly. Please can you update the code for me

Comment: @Kerry `I am getting promise rejection error` what error are you getting. My guess it's CORS error. If it is you need to set up a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) for development assuming you are hosting the app in production on the same url as the api.